# AngularJS $watch for value changes after initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this situation where I need to capture the event when a model is changed but the initialization in my directive triggers the event too early.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2T0Rq6yOXHWxQAOv8RpX?p=preview

How can I overcome this? Setting some flags, but how/where? Other approaches?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I added the `value` attribute to the directive so you can understand better what I mean by initialization.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/a5fzJi7VzAytj3Urj06L?p=preview

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "too early"

Comment: @DavinTryon My directive checks if the model is defined. If not, it initializes the model with "0". But this change/initialization triggers the $watch from the controller and I don't want this as it is now a real change from the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it finally!

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/a5fzJi7VzAytj3Urj06L?p=preview

The `form` directive in Angular has a property called `$dirty`. It starts as false and when you change the value of an input, the `ngModel` directive makes the form "dirty". First I tried to use `ngModel` in my directives but I ended up requiring using the `form` directly.

PS. This is triggered only on the first change, but this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You didn't have a form element in your initial sample.

Comment: I know :( It's because I tried to simplify the question as much as possible.

Comment: Nice, I was puzzled with this problem too. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You define `data` as

```
$scope.data = { x: 51 }
```

Later during parsing Angular detects that there are two more properties: `y` and `z` and they are undefined. In directive you set them to `0` in this case. So your data object becomes

```
{ x: 51, y: 0, z: 0 }
```

Obviously that `$scope.data` has changed and watcher should fire. This is why it happens.

To solve this you can simply define `data` with initial `y` and `z` values:

```
$scope.data = { x: 51, y: 0, z: 0 };
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/RfztKvrxhzPYMoSss7Fm?p=preview

Comment: I understand why it happens :) I just need a way to overcome this without setting initial values in data, because I don't know what properties should be set in the controller.

Comment: Well then you can also compare number of data properties in the old and new values. http://plnkr.co/edit/RfztKvrxhzPYMoSss7Fm?p=preview. You only want to fire watcher if this number is the same, meaning that property changed but not added (if it was undefined before).

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works, but isn't it a little hacky? If I add a new value it won't be triggered. http://plnkr.co/edit/vTyrejMdrFh6Dty98USI?p=preview

Comment: I agree that it's not ideal. Trying to come up with better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if a property exists on an object. [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KlyOEf7fyQ00uQVGc5WM?p=preview)

```
 if ((newValue !== oldValue) && oldValue.x) {
```

or maybe a more precise [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UBKhWAg8JzJdKT70OTZ5?p=preview):

```
if ((newValue !== oldValue) && (typeof oldValue.x !== 'undefined')) {
```

Comment: The properties may change, so I can't check on that.

Comment: But you check if the property is defined or undefined. In your statement data = {} the properties x,y,z are initially undefined and then setting them to 0 or any other number they are defined.

Comment: Your solution requires me to know at least one of the properties, which I don't know. Also you assume everything is initialized in one digest cycle.